# Sparring with Google: search has suddenly started requesting CAPTCHA constantly

Tags: networking, security, browser, captcha

### War with Google

A couple of months ago, our office was suddenly thrown into turmoil when Google decided to go to war with us.  Our identities were at stake: Google was sure that the office consisted only of robots - but we desperately cleared every CAPTCHA in an attempt to maintain neutrality and assure Google we were indeed human.  Since then there has been a war of attrition in which my patience has been worn thin.  I've decided to go on the offensive and see if anything can be done.

### The facts:

- We've had no problem with CAPTCHA until about 2 months ago.  At that time, everyone in the office suddenly noticed that almost every single google search was requesting the user to complete CAPTCHA .
- The CAPTCHA method has gotten worse as well:  The first week or so, we only got checkboxes to tick.  Then we got the images gallery to choose the right images from.  Now it's even worse: first we get a jumble of letters to type into a box and submit, then we get images to pick from, and lastly a checkbox.
- The CAPTCHA occurs constantly.  It's not every single google search, but very frequent, every 5 mins or so.  I think it may depend on how many requests the office submits as a whole.
- Most people here use Chrome, I use Vivaldi, and some people use Edge as their browser.  All get CAPTCHA's.
- The issue occurs for everyone using google search as far as I have found out.
- The office is on a fibre network, 200Mbps up/down and low latency.  About 50% of the computers use VPN, which still has the issue.
- The CAPTCHA issue also occurs on smartphone if connected to wifi.
- However **it does not occur** when using an incognito window.

I personally use Vivaldi browser which is built on Chromium and I'm not keen to change because I'm very happy with it.  It's the best browser I've used so far.  My observations would also indicate that this isn't browser dependent as it's happening across the office.  However, as an incognito window will foil the CAPTCHA, it seems possible that the browser can affect it in some way?

### Question:

I'm after anything that can help solve this, will appreciate any advice given.  It really isn't practical to use an incognito window all the time.  Is there a workaround to skip CATPCHA?  or a fix?  Could a free VPN fix this?  Can I change the standard headers that my browser submits to match those from an incognito window?  Put my traffic through a TOR proxy (yeah desperate times call for desperate measures).

Comment: Nice try skin job

Comment: Can you switch IPs? Can you check if there is a malware infection somewhere in your network? Usually when you remove the malware things go back to normal after a couple of days. Do not use TOR

Comment: uhm - assuming y'all use the same IP, that might indicate some system in your network is compromised and google considers your IP suspecious

Comment: All would be same IP, yep.  No malware as far as I know but that's the obvious answer...  I'll do some searching online to see how to find out...  ahh, that might take a while actually :)

Comment: A lot of posts about this issue refer to clearing cookies, settings etc.  I suppose if just one person has something weird going on, it would affect everyone on the IP?

Comment: If one person has malware installed, the entire IP could be "punished" for it. Run MalwareBytes Free on all computers.

Comment: @Gantendo: It can't be the IP, if VPN does not solve the problem.

Comment: @harrymc Depends. If I use the VPN to scrape google, and you are the next user, you will get captchas.

Comment: The VPN is a business solution provided by the company if that's any help.  A VPN would generally mask the original IP wouldn't it?

Comment: @5Diraptor Yep, if configured correctly. BTW while installing MalwareBytes, do not install the browser addon.

Comment: @5Diraptor: Do you mean that externally the VPN presents the same public IP as your entire network? What's the purpose of this VPN? Does your company have a static IP? From the fact that Incognito mode works I would guess that some extension you have installed company-wide is responsible for it. Try to disable all extensions and re-enable one by one until the problem reappears.

Comment: @harrymc - I don't know what IP the VPN would present - I would have thought a standard VPN would mask the IP?  The purpose of the VPN is internet security - most staff have laptops and we have a WFH program in place.  As far as I know it was just easier to install a generic VPN on everyone's PC rather then trying to manage who needs it and who doesn't.

Comment: @5Diraptor: If the VPN server is installed in the local network, it doesn't help. If it isn't local, this supports the notion that the cause is some extension.

Comment: It's a cloud based VPN.  So the most likely cause is that everyone has had something installed that triggers the recaptcha error?  or could this still be caused by a single PC?

Comment: @5Diraptor: The extension theory is easy to test.

Comment: @5Diraptor If a single pc is spreading malware, and Google detects it, then they will require captchas for all pcs using that IP. So if the malware infected pc has used the normal internet connection and the company VPN everyone will be filling in captchas until the infection is removed.